# Saving Excel sheet from python using xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I use a propriety addin in Excel to calculate financial maths functions.  I would like to save the results in a csv file for further manipulation.   How do I save Sheet2 as mytestfile.csv and then save and close Excel?

```
wb = xw.Book(path1 + "1VALVBA.xlsm") 
wb.app.api.RegisterXLL("C:/Windows/System32/vsoft15.xll")`enter code here`
# activate addin
wb.macro("ScreenASX1")()
# Run the VBA in Excel.  Results appear in Sheet2
sheet = wb.sheets['Sheet2']
```